# React Hook setData not updating properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have my setData as follows:

```
    type Data = {
      tempId: string,
      ...
    };

const [data: Data, setData: Data] = useState(() => {
    const data: Data = {
    };

    for (const [key, value] of formData) {
      if (key !== 'tempId') {
        data[key] = value;
      }
    }

    return data;
  });
```

and later on I call

```
setData({tempId: 'some_id', ...data});
```

However tempId shows up as never having been set and it is null. I have no idea why this could be happening -any ideas?

Comment: It is not very clear what is in formData, but I think tempId is over-riding to initial value when you're spreading data.
You should always spread data first and then assign new values so that it is not over-ridden - setData({ ...data, tempId: 'some_id'});

Comment: @VIshalJain it is just a map of values (those are set fine so that is not the issue) and yes I have tried spreading the data first but it did not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

useState accepts an initial value which will be the value of `data` in your example. The function you're passing wont get run like you think. You're probably looking for something like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();

const updateData = (formData) => {
  let data = {}

  for (const [key, value] of formData) {
    if (key !== 'tempId') {
      data[key] = value;
    }
  }

  setData(data)
}
```

Then instead of calling `setData({tempId: 'some_id', ...data});` you'd call `updateData({tempId: 'some_id', ...data});`

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I get "Cannot call `updateData` with object literal bound to `formData` because property `@@iterator` is missing in  object literal [1] but exists in  `$Iterable` [2]." when trying to call it via updateData({tempId: 'some_id', ...data});

Comment: I'm not familiar with flow, is there a way to type it with something like `any` for now?